# How to sort array by order status

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with date, status and summ:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-07-06 14:01:52
            [status] => paid
            [summ] => 100

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-07-02 12:22:31
            [summ] => 320
            [status] => pending
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-07-01 18:43:58
            [summ] => 100
            [status] => pending
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-06-26 14:01:52
            [status] => canceled
            [summ] => 200
        )
```

i need to sort this array by status first (1.pending, 2.paid, 3.canceled), and then by date (new at the top).

Order which i nedd:

pending 2019-07-02 12:22:31
pending 2019-07-01 18:43:58
paid 2019-07-06 14:01:52
canceled 2019-06-26 14:01:52

with date i don't have any problems:

```
usort($new11, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($b['date']) - strtotime($a['date']);
});
```

But how to sort by status in order which i need?

Thanx:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array using multiple criteria in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559050/sort-array-using-multiple-criteria-in-php)

Comment: You probably need to go through each item using for loop and do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Spaceship](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
<?php

    $new11 = [
        [
            'date' => '2019-07-06 14:01:52',
            'status' => 'paid',
            'summ' => 100,
        ],
        [
            'date' => '2019-07-02 12:22:31',
            'status' => 'pending',
            'summ' => 320,
        ],
        [
            'date' => '2019-07-01 18:43:58',
            'status' => 'pending',
            'summ' => 100,
        ],
        [
            'date' => '2019-06-26 14:01:52',
            'status' => 'canceled',
            'summ' => 200,
        ],
    ];

    $pending = 3;
    $paid = 2;
    $canceled = 1;

    usort($new11, function($a, $b) use ($pending, $paid, $canceled) {
        return (${$b['status']} <=> ${$a['status']}) * 10 +
               (strtotime($b['date']) <=> strtotime($a['date']));
    });


    var_dump($new11);
```

[demo](https://www.tehplayground.com/ztM6eKYuxC2xBQH9)

Comment: ${$a['status']}) * 10

Why 10?:)

Comment: @AlexB cause <==> returns -1,1 or 0 :) so summary filter will be (-1,0,1) * 10 + (-1,0,1)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.array-multisort.php) to achieve it:

```
$test = [
    [
        'date' => '2019-07-06 14:01:52',
        'status' => 'paid',
        'summ' => 100,
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2019-07-02 12:22:31',
        'status' => 'pending',
        'summ' => 320,
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2019-07-01 18:43:58',
        'status' => 'pending',
        'summ' => 100,
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2019-06-26 14:01:52',
        'status' => 'canceled',
        'summ' => 200,
    ],
];

array_multisort(
    array_column($test, 'status'),
    SORT_DESC,
    array_column($test, 'date'),
    SORT_DESC,
    $test
);

var_dump($test);
```

The result would be:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2019-07-02 12:22:31"
    ["status"]=>
    string(7) "pending"
    ["summ"]=>
    int(320)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2019-07-01 18:43:58"
    ["status"]=>
    string(7) "pending"
    ["summ"]=>
    int(100)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2019-07-06 14:01:52"
    ["status"]=>
    string(4) "paid"
    ["summ"]=>
    int(100)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2019-06-26 14:01:52"
    ["status"]=>
    string(8) "canceled"
    ["summ"]=>
    int(200)
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/8Caql)

Comment: how did you set priority of statuses?

Comment: @AlexB He just sorted it alphabetically but descending from z to a

Answer (score 0):

You could sort it using [asort](https://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php), which order it alphabetically.

If you need it with certain status order, I would recommend use int values to reference the status. Could use some Constraints to define them

Comment: Idea!:) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. You could have an array of priority with values assigned. Then, you could do simple math operations to judge the result.

```
<?php

usort($new11, function($a, $b) {
    $priority = [
                    'pending' => 1,
                    'paid' => 2,
                    'canceled' => 3
                ];

    $result = $priority[$a['status']] - $priority[$b['status']];
    if($result === 0) return strtotime($b['date']) - strtotime($a['date']);
    return $result;    
});
```